# How to I call a function when form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Below is my part in my html page which is  to get a threshold value and to call a function with the value

```
<form id="distance_input" onSubmit="return false;" >  


    <p>Enter a  threshold</p>

    <div class="col-md-8" style="display: inline-block; left:-30px">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="input-group"> 

      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" class="search" onkeydown="search(this)"> </input>
    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 50px">km</span>
    </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:0px; margin-left:-10px">

     <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" id="myButton"> </input>

    </div>
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
     </form> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myButton').click(function(){
        var value = $("input[type=text]").val();
            console.log(value+ " from the submit button");
            set_to_threshold(value);


        });

    function search(ele) {
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            console.log(ele.value+" from enter button");   
            set_tothreshold(ele.value);

        }
    } 
</script>
```

But when I do this I get the graphs do not get refreshed( set_tothreshold function gets new data for graph when the value is passes in the function) and shows that

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: search is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeydown
```

when I tried with

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
            var value = $("input[type=text]").val();
                console.log(value+ " from the submit button");
                set_to_threshold(value);


            });


    </script>
```

also when I press submit button no changes happened(even does not prints value in console).But why does the value does not get printed.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why not bind your keydown with jQuery too?

Comment: Where is your search function declared/defined?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
      var value = $("input[type=text]").val();
            console.log(value);
      set_to_threshold(value);
      
    });

   function set_to_threshold(val){
     console.log('do something here with val ', val);
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <input type="text" value="input something"/>
  <button id="myButton">click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $( "button" ).on( "click", notify );
alternative to this could be to use on('event', function() { do something });

Answer (score 0):

this is what you want . yourfunction call when form submit

```
<form id="distance_input" onSubmit="yourFunction(); return false;" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly include jquery in your file. It works fine.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Include this at the head section of the html page. And also there u referred function `set_to_threshold()` which is undefined. So only you are getting the error. Kindly write a function for it. it'll work!